# (Shell Script) Count Items in a directory and display them out

Tags: bash, shell, count, counter

**(Shell Script) Count Items in a directory and display them out**

I have some code that lists the items in a directory using `ls` However I was wondering if there was a way to count the number of items in the directory and display the number. For example my code so far is:

```
cd /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files && ls
```

The code above is locating my trash can, where my deleted files are located. Let's say that I have something that looks like this:

```
Music
Wallpapers
Movies
Etc
```

How can I instead make it look like this:

```
There are [4] Items in this directory:

1. Music
2. Wallpapers
3. Movies
4. Etc
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe ls to nl:

```
cd /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files && ls | nl -s '. '
```

If you really want the header, pipe it to awk:

```
ls | nl -s '.  ' | awk '
  {c+=1; e=e RS $0} END {print "There are [" c "] Items in this directory"  RS e}'
```

or just skip the `nl`:

```
ls | awk '                       
  {e=e RS NR ".  " $0} END {print "There are [" NR "] Items in this directory"  RS e}'
```

These will miscount if you have any files in the directory that contain newlines in their name.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what you mean by 'newlines' in their name. Do you mean if there is spacing between the words? Anyways, it woks well so far.

Comment: A file name *can* contain a newline; doing so is discouraged because people erroneously write code like this that assumes that a file name *won't* contain a newline.